# Avoid "$" being URLEncoded

Tags: java, urlencode

I have a string that contains "$" in it. Because of the problem mentioned in [URLEncode a value of Map in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301872/urlencode-a-value-of-map-in-spring), I have to URLEncode it. But I don't want encode method to encode "$" as well.

Is there any way this can be done?

**Editing question as I wasn't clear in the beginning**:

I am trying to avoid a java change and see if I can make this change at spring config. So trying to understand if there is any escape character that would make URLEncode not encode $ and encode rest of it

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"But I don't want encode method to encode "$" as well."* Why not?

Comment: Indeed. Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Smells like odata ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, the reason is, I need $ in the post processing.

Comment: @user1401472: Presumably you'll URL-decode it at the other end, before further processing.

Comment: May a URL contain an unencoded $? Because if it may not, what you are asking for makes no sense.

Comment: URL should have an unencoded $. Thats when the post processor will do a string replacement.

Answer (score 1):

you can split your string with `$`, url encode all the elements in the array you get, and glue it back with `$`